# Using PnPJS Library to display list of data

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, react, react-webpart

I'm building a SPFX React webpart. I currently have the webpart on my SharePoint site's workbench page.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
  private _renderListAsync(): void {
    // Local Enviroment
    if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {
        console.log('This is local!');
    }
    else if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.SharePoint || Environment.type === EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {
        console.log('This is Sharepoint!!');
            pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Data").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
                items.map((item) => {
                    console.log(item);
                    console.log(item.Full_Name);
                    return item.Full_Name;
                })

        });
    }
}
```

In my console I'm able to see all the data from that item. And if I do a `console.log(item.Full_Name)` I see all the data there. However when I try to return the item on the page it displays `null`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, Are you using javascript-based SPFx webpart or React based SPFx webpart?

Comment: @ShanthaKumarThambidurai sorry, it's in react typescript

Answer (score 1):

Define interface to store your list  data.

```
export interface IReactItem {
  ID: string,
  Title: string,
  Address: string
  Pic: {
    Description: string,
    Url: string
  }
}
```

init data in

```
public componentDidMount() {
// your pnp code

var reactHandler = this;
    this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?select=ID,Title,Address,Pic`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
          reactHandler.setState({
            items: responseJSON.value.sort()
          });
        });
      });
```

Render in render

```
return (
      <div className={styles.reactSpFx}>

        <div className={styles.container}>        
          <div className={styles.img} title="Rencore logo">content</div>         

          {(this.state.items || []).map((item, index) => (
            <div key={item.ID} className={(index % 2 == 0) ? styles.rowA : styles.rowB}>{item.Title}
              {index % 2}
              {this.renderPic(item)}
              //your render template
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```